# Get Key Value Given Other Key Value in FireBase

Tags: javascript, firebase, object, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to find a way to find the value of the `id` given the `email`.

For example, If I had `email2@gmail.com`, It would give me the ID `108454568498950432898`.

All emails are unique and there will be no repetition of emails.

This is my user tree:

[image]

**Note: In the image it says *email2* instead of *email2@gmail.com*. Ignore this**

Here's my code so far:
(Code won't run obviously but it's easier to enter code using the embed)

```js
var users;
var givenEmail = "email2@gmail.com";
var neededID;

var dataRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
dataRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    users = data;
});

var usersArray = Object.keys(users);

for(i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i++) {
    if(users[i].email == givenEmail) {
        neededID = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) to perform the filtering on the server, instead of downloading the entire `users` node and filtering in your application code as you now do.

```
var givenEmail = "email2@gmail.com";

var dataRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
var query = dataRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo(givenEmail);
dataRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
        console.log(userSnapshot.val().id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you are almost there.

```
users[i].email
```

you can retrieve the email using this method, and similarly you can do it with **id** too

```
users[i].id
```

Please note that you wanted to find **email2@gmail.com** but your firebase only have **email2**

Maybe you would want to change that

Comment: Ah Sorry... Small mistake when I was changing my values for my privacy. I'll just add a sidenote. Thanks for the answer though?

Comment: then you should only change this
neededID = users[i].id;

Comment: It's giving me undefined in the 'users' variable, but there's not problem with the 'dataRef' variable. It only works if I run the function twice.